# How to add a button in admin grid in magento 2

Tags: grid, magento2.2.3, custom-button

I wish to add button field in layout grid(without using UI component), After adding button, also need to add click function to that field. Please provide me a solution to add button as a field in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to add a separate button with some required action.
In that case, you can load the row with renderer file, in that renderer, you can call the PHTML template, like below.

```
public function render(DataObject $row)
{
    $block = <load-your-block-file>;
    $block->setTemplate('path/to/template.phtml');
    return $block->toHtml();
}
```

And I hope you can load your button with $row as dynamic data for required action